# Cannot find & therefore remove an application

Tags: 16.04, software-uninstall

I recently noticed I have 2 zoom versions on my PC running Ubuntu 16.04.
I would like to remove one version I suspect is not the original one.
Using `apt-get remove` just removed the good version I used.

Now there's a Zoom app I can see in Applications (when pressing `~` and typing `Zoom`) but I cannot remove it with `apt-get`, it's not in ubuntu software center, I cannot grep it's process even (`ps -ef|grep zoom`), `type/which zoom` doesn't find it, and haven't found any solution regarding how to find where it's installed and then remove it.

Never tackled such a thing and couldn't find info regarding how to deal with it.

[image]

Output of apt-cache:

```
(garage) ➜  ~ apt-cache search zoom
eog - Eye of GNOME graphics viewer program
eog-dbg - Eye of GNOME graphics viewer program - debugging symbols
libjs-jquery-fancybox - fancy lightbox alternative
aview - A high quality ASCII art image viewer and video player
berusky2 - logic game Bugs Escape 3D
berusky2-data - logic game Bugs Escape 3D -- data files
caca-utils - text mode graphics utilities
cbrpager - viewer for CBR, CBZ and CB7 (comic book archive) files
cgview - Circular Genome Viewer
comix - GTK Comic Book Viewer
darktable - virtual lighttable and darkroom for photographers
dvilx - dvi viewer for X
endless-sky-high-dpi - space exploration and combat game
eog-plugins - set of plugins for eog
eom - Eye of MATE graphics viewer program
eom-common - Eye of MATE graphics viewer program (common files)
eom-dbg - Eye of MATE graphics viewer program (debugging symbols)
eom-dev - Eye of MATE graphics viewer program (development files)
feh - imlib2 based image viewer
felix-latin - Félix Gaffiot's Latin-French dictionary - viewer
foobillardplus - 3D OpenGL Billiard Game
fractgen - Extensible Fractal Generator
gbrowse - GMOD Generic Genome Browser
geeqie - image viewer using GTK+
geeqie-common - data files for Geeqie
geeqie-dbg - debug symbols for Geeqie
gir1.2-eom - GObject introspection data for the eom library
gliv - image viewer using gdk-pixbuf and OpenGL
gnome-maps - map application for GNOME
golly - Game of Life simulator using hashlife algorithm
gpxviewer - views GPS traces collected in the GPX format
hovercraft - generator for impress.js presentations from reStructuredText
iipimage-doc - Web-based streamed viewing and zooming of ultra high-resolution images - doc
iipimage-server - Web-based streamed viewing and zooming of ultra high-resolution images
imview - Image viewing and analysis application
invesalius - 3D medical imaging reconstruction software
jmapviewer - Java OpenStreetMap Tile Viewer
katarakt - simple PDF viewer with two layouts
kwave - sound editor for KDE
libgeo-google-mapobject-perl - module managing the server side of the Google Maps API
libgeo-osm-tiles-perl - module for calculating tile numbers for OpenStreetMap
libghc-sdl-gfx-dev - Haskell SDL gfx binding for GHC
libghc-sdl-gfx-doc - Haskell SDL gfx binding for GHC - documentation
libghc-sdl-gfx-prof - Haskell SDL gfx binding for GHC - profiling libraries
libgtk2-imageview-perl - Perl bindings for the GtkImageView image viewer widget
libgtkdatabox-0.9.2-0 - Gtk+ library to display large amounts of numerical data
libgtkdatabox-0.9.2-0-dev - Gtk+ library to display large amounts of numerical data (development)
libgtkdatabox-0.9.2-0-doc - Gtk+ library to display large amounts of numerical data (API doc)
libgtkdatabox-0.9.2-0-glade - Gtk+ library to display large amounts of numerical data (glade API)
libgtkdatabox-0.9.2-0-libglade - Gtk+ library to display large amounts of numerical data (glade lib)
libgtkimageview-dev - image viewer widget for GTK+ (development files)
libgtkimageview0 - image viewer widget for GTK+
libjs-flotr - plotting library for the Prototype Framework
libjs-iscroll - High performance, small footprint JavaScript scroller
libjs-jquery-flot - plotting library for jQuery
libjs-jquery-flot-docs - Documentation for Flot
libjs-jquery-fullscreen - jQuery FullScreen Plugin
libjs-jquery-fullscreen-plugin - plugin for showing any DOM element on a page in fullscreen mode
libjs-polymaps - JavaScript library for image- and vector-tiled maps
libnet-z3950-simple2zoom-perl - gateway between Z39.50 and SRU/SRW
libnet-z3950-zoom-perl - Perl extension implementing the ZOOM API for Information Retrieval via Z39.50
libpiccolo-java - toolkit for development of 2D structured graphics
libsdl-gfx1.2-5 - drawing and graphical effects extension for SDL
libsdl-gfx1.2-dev - development files for SDL_gfx
libsdl-gfx1.2-doc - documentation files for SDL_gfx
libsdl2-gfx-1.0-0 - drawing and graphical effects extension for SDL2
libsdl2-gfx-dbg - debugging symbols for SDL2_gfx
libsdl2-gfx-dev - development files for SDL2_gfx
libsdl2-gfx-doc - documentation files for SDL2_gfx
libyazpp4 - YAZ++ and ZOOM library
libyazpp4-dev - Development libraries for YAZ++ and ZOOM
libyazpp4-doc - Documentation for YAZ++
links2 - Web browser running in both graphics and text mode
mirage - fast and simple GTK+ image viewer
mmass - Mass spectrometry tool for proteomics
mmass-modules - Mass spectrometry tool for proteomics - extension modules
node-iscroll - High performance, small footprint JavaScript scroller  NodeJS module
ocamlgraph-editor - graphical graph editor based on hyperbolic geometry
pdfcube - PDF document viewer with 3D effects
petri-foo - MIDI controllable audio sampler - successor of specimen
petri-foo-dbg - Debugging symbols for petri-foo
pgbadger - Fast PostgreSQL log analysis report
phototonic - image viewer and organizer
pqiv - Lightweight image viewer
python-qwt - Pure Python implementation of Qwt - Python 2
python-qwt-doc - Pure Python implementation of Qwt - Documentation
python-visual - VPython 3D scientific visualization library
python-wxmpl - Painless matplotlib embedding in wxPython
python3-qwt - Pure Python implementation of Qwt - Python 3
qiv - Quick image viewer for X
qliss3d - demonstration tool for Lissajous figures
quickplot - fast interactive 2D plotter and data viewer
ruby-zoom - Ruby/ZOOM provides a Ruby binding to the Z40.50 Object-Orientation Model
saods9 - Image display tool for astronomy
sozi - inkscape extension for creating animated presentations
starplot - 3-dimensional perspective star map viewer
sugar-imageviewer-activity - Sugar Learning Platform - image viewing activity
viewpdf.app - Portable Document Format (PDF) viewer for GNUstep
wbar-config - GUI tool to configure wbar
xaos - real-time interactive fractal zoomer
xdot - interactive viewer for Graphviz dot files
xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin - rapid launcher plugin for the Xfce4 panel
xgraph - Plotting program, reads stdin, allows interactive zooming
xloadimage - Graphics file viewer under X11
xplot - simple on-screen x-y column data plotter
xplot-xplot.org - fast tool to graph and visualize lots of data
xscreensaver-data-extra - Extra screen saver modules for screensaver frontends
xsddiagram - XML Schema Definition (XSD) diagram viewer
xzoom - magnify part of X display, with real-time updates
yorick-spydr - FITS image display and simple analysis
zegrapher - plotting mathematical functions and sequences on the plane
zoneminder - video camera security and surveillance solution
zoneminder-dbg - Zoneminder -- debugging symbols
zoneminder-doc - ZoneMinder documentation
zoom-player - player for Z-Code stories or games
zoomer - generate a video from a picture by zooming from one point to another
xfractint - UNIX-based fractal generator
```

Comment: Was it a [snap](https://snapcraft.io/zoom-client) or [flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/us.zoom.Zoom) install perhaps?

Comment: Open a terminal and type `apt-cache search zoom` and then edit your question with the output.

Comment: @kortewegdevries Not a snap install, never used flatpak

Comment: @darth_epoxy Couldn't find something relevant there, added anyway

Comment: OK then try this `apt list --installed` and see if your zoom was installed via apt.

Comment: Please add output of `grep -ir "exec.*zoom" /usr/share/applications/ ~/.local/share/applications/ ~ --include=*.desktop` and `which zoom` to the question.

Comment: @darth_epoxy I grepped zoom and nothing.

Comment: @N0rbert First outputs no matches, second outputs zoom is not found. I added a picture showing I do have something called zoom installed, and it opens up successfully, not just a leftover icon..

Comment: Sounds strange, try to dig deeper with `sudo grep -ir "exec.*zoom" / --include=*.desktop --include=*.menu` .

Comment: @N0rbert No matches found

Comment: `sudo grep -ir "name.*zoom" / --include=*.desktop --include=*.menu` ?

Comment: @N0rbert No matches found